# Give Link to Toast Notification in windows 8 application

Tags: microsoft-metro, toast, windows

I am developing an app for windows 8 , in which I want the toast to have link to any webpage or any other metro application rather than the own application.
note:The web link or App Name will be entered by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported. Toasts can only take the user to the application that sent the toast. See below.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx):

> A toast notification can contain text and/or images, but secondary
>   actions such as buttons are not supported.

and

> When a user taps or clicks the notification, the associated app is
>   launched and the user can expect that the resulting view is related to
>   the content of the notification. It is the only mechanism by which one
>   app can interrupt a user in another app.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this :

create a new xaml page with WebBrowser element and use following code to easily navigate to webpage.

[image: Code Example]

Here On clicking the shell Toast it is navigated to the specific page inside your app specified in the url.

It's just a workaround it's not great but will partially accomplish your task.

Thanks .